Is it a good idea to trim branches that are not developing leaves?
1 minute video from Today: https://twitter.com/marsXRobertson/status/1787117174563143746
If you don't want to click, the TLDR is that a tree is developing two branches:

Healthy with leaves
Appears dry


Do you have some knowledge?
Both ways can be correct:

Let the nature do the thing?

Help the tree (humans as part of nature) and trim the part that is not so great?


Or maybe CitizenScience and do 50 / 50 see what happens next year... But I don't want to wait, I much prefer to tap into existing experience.

Trimming dead branches when you are sure they are dead is good. Don't cut the branch collar, and don't leave too long of a stub - both so the tree can heal the wound as fast as possible.
And don't put any products on the cut (they have been debunked as worse than useless multiple times, but they still sell them and publish misinformation to maintain sales.)

The question remains: is the branch dead, for sure? It just does not produce any leaves... Maybe it has some life? Hard to tell... Have you seen 1 minute video that I've posted? It's not completely dry. HMMM... Ask twice, cut once :)

"It just does not produce any leaves" But all the other branches are fully leafed out. Not a particularly good application of "just" - that's a rather serious problem for a plant part that depends on leaves processing sunlight to live. It would appear that the other branches leafed out weeks ago. You can leave it a month more if you like, but it already seems highly unlikely that it will make leaves at all.

Ah we need to repeat ancient wisdom again? Fine.

get a knife
cut a superficial wound along the branch, not across, less than 1 cm
green? - alive; but it won't be
or just straight up cut it down
closing the wound with chemicals - I disagree with the other answer; but it's mostly pointless

